# Can I create a proper drop down menu list in windows phone, nothing like Picker Box, ListPicker, AutoCompleteBox achieving my objective properly?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to create a drop down menu in my windows phone silverlight application, from which user can select a mobile service provider amongst many of them, i.e user can select a Big Tv amonst Airtel Dth, Oxicash, Big Tv etc.

Why everyone suggesting to other options for this like ListPicker, AutoCompleteBox, PickerBox etc?

Here is the code for ListPicker,when I select an item,there is a weird vibration in the list, pleaase let me know where i am doing wrong?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="ListPickedDemo.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
 xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanell" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <toolkit:ListPicker Margin="12,6,6,302" Name="lstPicker">

            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="First Item" />

            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Second Item" />

            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Third Item" />

        </toolkit:ListPicker>

    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

I have used `ListPicker` `AutoCompleteox` etc.
Nothing is achiving my objective properly,please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: Which is the reason the other options are not achieving your objective properly?

Comment: If none provide the functionality you need then you can design your own control or modify one of them to implement your specific requirements.

Comment: like for example, when I created List picker, I am unable to select a particular item and if I am using AutoCompleteBox, then there is nothing like dropdown menu,I have to type some initials of the menu item,then it is displayed there. While I want that when i click on the list box, a drop down menu sholud be diplayed @anderZubi

Comment: plz let me know,how to do this @AlaaMasoud

Comment: Why aren't you able to select items from ListPicker control? It's the purpose of that control, to pick an item from a list of them

Comment: The ListPicker control IS a combobox (plus more!) can you please share the code you are using that is not working

Comment: @ShawnKendrot
yes here is the code,when I select an item,there is a weird vibration in the list, pleaase let me know where i am doing wrong?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot
u can see code from the question itself.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Are you testing on an actual device? Emulator is nice but has limitations of being run on your machine and consuming your machine resources. Can you explain the flicker more?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot
what is left to tell?Do you have some code for Drop Down Menu?

Comment: Nothing left, what you have works great. I've tested. That is the code for  dropdown. Again, are you testing on an actual device?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot
I have fixed the the problem of flickering, but now the new problem is that it's not working for more than four or five items, i.e when there is more than five items in the list, there is a weird display.

Comment: Have you seen the answer I provided?

Answer (score 1):

The [ListPicker](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/ListPicker/ListPicker.cs) has a property ItemCountThreshold. This property allows you to specify when the ListPicker should display the full screen selector. This property defaults to 5. You can change the default to a much high number, but you should take caution with doing this. The ListPicker is meant to mimic controls that are used throughout the core apps (like Settings) of the phone. You'd have a hard time finding built in apps that show more than five items in the "dropdown".

When displaying in FullMode, you should specify a FullModeItemTemplate and FullModeHeader. The FullModeHeader should be in all caps