# How to build dropdown menu in wp7, I have tried ListPicker but its not working for long list?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I need a drop down menu in my windows phone silverlight app, from which user can select a choice, for example user can select his/her district from drop down menu of districts.

I have tried `ListPicker` but its not working for a long items list, i.e if I am giving more then five items to list, there is a weird output.
Please help me.

Comment: You need to create your own implementation. Create programmatically a Popup, and add controls to it. Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352095/scrolling-contextmenu-items) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928514/scrollable-listpicker-items-list)? First question has a detailed explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "weird output"? What have you actually done? Beware trying to create controls from other platforms that don't exist natively on Windows Phone--this is not what users will expect and is likely to create much more work for you than using native controls.

Comment: Please see this same exact post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675296/can-i-create-a-proper-drop-down-menu-list-in-windows-phone-nothing-like-picker/17750762#17750762

Answer (score 0):

Go for

> LongListSelector

in Microsoft phone controls toolkit...

Answer (score 0):

It is not "weird output", it that how `ListPicker` control works. `ListPicker` behaves differently depending on the amount of items. If it has upt ot 5 items, it shows as in-place selection list. However, if it has more items, it shows as a fullscreen popup. You can set the  `FullModeItemTemplate` property to change how it looks when fullscreen.

Find more info here:

[ListPicker for WP7 in depth](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)